# How to use Google Analytics with Phonegap in android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am making an app in  android and I want to get analytics from the users. I tried to use the Phonegap Plugin, but I didn't have any luck trying to implement it.

I was wondering if it was possible to get Google Analytics by treating the app like a normal webpage and putting some javascript in the head of my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggeling with that GAplugin recently. So this is what I did:

1: if you're using phonegap build just place this in your config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
```

2: on the google analytics page create a new mobile app.

3: place the plugin in your index.html

```
 <script src="GAPlugin.js"></script>
```

4: place the following code in your onDeviceReady function.

```
gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
gaPlugin.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "UA-12345678-1", 10);
```

5: track a page like this:

```
gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler,     "some.url.com");
```

more information can be found here:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/blob/master/README.md